# In which chapter of the Mahabharatha the story of Bhisma giving five arrows to Duryodhana for killing the Pandavas is found?

Tags: mahabharata

There are several posts on the internet that mention that Duryodahan once received 5 arrows that were charged by Bhishma to kill the Pandavas, which Arjuna took away from Duryodhana at the advice of Sri Krishna.

Where does this happen in the Mahabharatha? I believe it will be a part of the Bhishma Parva, Can someone please help me with chapter number?

Answer (score 1):

This story is described to be a part of the Bhishma Parva. But this is a solklore.

The [Critical Edition of Mahabharata Bhishma Parva](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m06/index.htm) does not have this incident.

Comment: That's not the critical edition.  Ganguli's translation is based on the Mahabharata as it's present in manuscripts, not the critical edition. Bibek Debroy's translation is based on the critical edition though.

Comment: Thank you @KeshavSrinivasan. The Kumbhakonam edition has much more than the Ganguli's translation. If it were not the critical one, i wonder why they chose to ignore a lot of the Kumbhakonam recension and chose to be more in line with the critical edition. A good example is the Ashwamedha parva wehre Ganguli translation stops at 95th verse while the kumbhakonam edition goes on to give the discussion between Kesava and Yudhistira where the former instructs the later on dharma.

Comment: I correct my previous comment, BORI has 96 while the kumbhakonam has 118. My question on it is here https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/23655/what-are-the-major-differences-between-the-critical-edition-of-mahabharatha-and