# What are the major differences between the Critical edition of Mahabharatha and the Kumbhakonam edition?

Tags: mahabharata, critical-edition

There seems to be a lot of difference between the Critical edition of Mahabharatha and the Kumbhakonam edition. One major difference is the Aswamedha parva where the Critical edition cuts it at 96 while the Kumbhakonam edition goes until 118.

[Reference Link to Kumbhakonam edition.](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/mbhK/mahabharata-k-14-sa.html)

[Reference Link to BORI edition.](https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/pdf/mbh-14.pdf)

What i seek is the major parts (not all) that were removed and the reason (if deemed as interpolation, why so)?